# Postman test script: what version of JavaScript

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

what version of JavaScript is allowed in `Postman` test script?

I tried to look this up from Postman's document but the answer is not obvious.  For example, I looked at the [official document of Postman Sandbox Execution Environment](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox/)

Comment: Is there a specific reason for knowing?

Comment: @Danny -- Just for completeness.  For example, I want to make sure that I would not be using syntax in later versions of JavaScript that is not accepted by `Postman`

Comment: There's a sure fire way to find out... :) I use `const`, `let` and arrow functions etc. Not sure what version those are part of but it's a starting point. You could have a play around to see what does and doesn't work.

Comment: @Danny -- Yes I know I can "reverse engineer" the version number.  But I just think it is better if the supported version is documented.  They already document the JavaScript libraries allowed in the sandbox environment.  Just wonder why they do not also document the supported JavaScript version.

Comment: What if it did and the documentation was out of date? :) This seems like a very specific question that might be worth asking in the place where you would get a specific answer - https://community.getpostman.com/t/welcome-to-discourse/8

Comment: @Danny -- Okay thanks!  I posted a message to Postman Community

Answer (score 0):

I've put some code together in order to display the java script version into the postman's visualizer - I could not figure out a way to get the value.

write this script below at your request "Test" (any request will suffice):

```html
    var template=`
    <script language="javascript">var js_version="1.0"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.1">var js_version="1.1"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.2">var js_version="1.2"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.3">var js_version="1.3"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.4">var js_version="1.4"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.5">var js_version="1.5"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.6">var js_version="1.6"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.7">var js_version="1.7"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.8">var js_version="1.8"</script>
    <script language="javascript1.9">var js_version="1.9"</script>
    assuming that visualizer uses the SAME script engine version used by postman: 
    <script language="javascript">
      document.write(js_version); 
    </script>
    `;
    pm.visualizer.set(template);
```

the version info will be displayed at the visualize tab into the body tab.